# Scheduling locust tasks on a timer

Tags: python, performance, locust

I want to be able to have a task that runs at a specified interval. For example, say I want to test 3 endpoints, but every 30 seconds I want to ping a `/status/` endpoint

```
class SomeTasks(TaskSet):
    @task
    self.get("/home/")

    @task
    self.get("/info/")
    
    @task
    self.get("/products/")

    @task
    self.get("/status/")

class SomeUser(FastHttpUser):
    tasks = [SomeTasks]
    wait_time = between(0, 0)
```

not sure how this could be run so that it would pick `/home/`, `/info/`, `/products/` randomly as usual, but every 30 seconds check the status. Maybe this could be put in the `SomeUser` class?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the pinging of `/status/` to be separate from you other user work. You want Locust to generate many users to hit `/home/`, `/info/`, `/products/` repeatedly as part of your test, but you want a single "user" to ping `/status/` once every 30 seconds? If so, it's possible but not very straightforward. I'd make a separate function outside of the normal `@task`s that runs repeatedly on its own timer but still reports to Locust.

There are multiple ways to do that but I lean towards using [Locust events](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#event-hooks) such as `@events.test_start.add_listener` to make Locust call a function when your test starts. In the function, create a greenlet that pings `/status/` endpoint in a loop every 30 seconds and reports to Locust. The the basic file below and the bit about making the loop conditional on test status is optional and taken from the [Locust examples](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/77deb7bdb8cf9e44df9c60324ae5a75cbec2fbe7/examples/stop_on_threshold.py).

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, constant, events
from locust.runners import STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP, WorkerRunner
from locust.clients import HttpSession

import gevent
import time
import os


@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(environment, **_kwargs):
    gevent.spawn(ping_status, environment)

def ping_status(environment):
    session = HttpSession(base_url=environment.host, request_success=environment.events.request_success, request_failure=environment.events.request_failure)
    while not environment.runner.state in [STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
        time.sleep(30)
        session.get("/status/")

class UserTasks(TaskSet):

    @task
    def page404(self):
        self.client.get("/does_not_exist")

    @task
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task
    def stats(self):
        self.client.get("/stats/requests")

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    host = "http://127.0.0.1:8089"
    wait_time = constant(2)
    tasks = [UserTasks]
```